# HTML Webpage Height Set

Tags: html, css

So my problem that I need help getting a solution in is that the height of my #pagewrap is getting set to about 820px (something near that) and don't have anything in my CSS that is setting the height.  Unfortunately, do to the fact the javascript I have on my webpage changes the pages dynamically automatically adjusting the page height, I cannot set a max-height because that would mess up my other pages.  I have tried many other max-heights for other objects, but I know it is the #page-wrap.  Even though yes, that javascript does change page heights.  I have used it in other sites that I have made and I don't think that it is the problem in this case.  I think that is something else.  What that is I don't know otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question in the first place.

Here is my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Anna at Nourish</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dynamicpage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
    var audioEl = document.getElementById("audioTag");

    audioEl.load();
    audioEl.play();
    };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (screen.width <= 700) {
            window.location = "http://m.757stylist.com";
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry/IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
            if(document.URL !="http://www.757stylist.index.html")
            {
                window.location ="http://m.757stylist.com/index.html";
            }
        }
    </script>
<meta name="description" content="Amazing Master Hair Stylist Anna Wenke Now at Nourish Day Spa,
Providing The Best in Cuts, Color, & Keratin-Treatments
Anna At Nourish is located in the newly remodeled Nourish Day Spa, a    Luxe Spa on Shore Drive in Virginia Beach one block from the Lesner Bridge. 

By Appointment Only 
(757) 777-4901
757stylist@gmail.com"><meta name="keywords" content="Anna   Wenke,757,stylist,hair,757 stylist,anna,wenke,hair,hair cuts,beauty salon,salon"><meta name="robots" content="follow,index"></head>
<body>
    <div id="hideme">
            <audio id="audioTag" controls loop>
                        <source src="sound/background.mp3">
            </audio>
    </div>
    <div id="page-wrap">
            <header id="top-nav">
                <nav>
                    <ul class="group">
                        <li id="head-image"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/mainimages/logo.png" alt="Anna at Nourish Logo" height="150"></a></li>
                        <li id="home-link"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li id="about-link"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li id="contact-link"><a href="unavailable.html">Products</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <li id="appointment-link"><a class="typeform-share link" href="https://jr8.typeform.com/to/d8NSmy" data-mode="1" target="_blank">Request An Appointment</a>
                    <script>(function(){var qs,js,q,s,d=document,gi=d.getElementById,ce=d.createElement,gt=d.getElementsByTagName,id='typef_orm',b='https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/share.typeform.com/';if(!gi.call(d,id)){js=ce.call(d,'script');js.id=id;js.src=b+'share.js';q=gt.call(d,'script')[0];q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q)}})()</script></li>
                <p id="contact-info"><a href="tel:(757) 777-4901">(757) 777-4901</a><br><a href="mailto:757stylist@gmail.com">757stylist@gmail.com</a><br>Mon-Sat: By Appointment<br>3700 Shore Drive, Suite 105, VA Beach</p>
                <img src="images/mainimages/bio-pic.png" width="100px" height="100px" style="position: relative; top: -335px; left: 440px;">
            </header>
            <section id="main-content">
                <div id="guts">
                    <div id="home-wrap">
                        <iframe height="440px;" width="850px" src="slicebox/index.html" style="border: 0px; position: relative; top: 10px; left: 45px; max-height: 440px; max-width: 850px; overflow: hidden;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
                        <div id="footer"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Anna-at-Nourish/339918796198673" id="face-link"><img src="images/mainimages/facebook.png" alt="facebook logo" height="64px" width="64px" style="position: relative; top: 25px; left: -5px; font: 40px bold;">Like Us On Facebook!</a><a href="http://www.jrtech12.com" style="position: relative; left: 300px; top: -35px; font: 20px bold;">This Website Was Created <br><p style="position: relative; left: 420px; top: -20px; font: 20px bold;">By JR Tech - &copy;2015</p></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
body {
overflow-y: scroll;
background:url(../images/browser/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
max-height: 775px;
}
#page-wrap {
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
width: 945px;
position: relative;
top: -40px;
max-width: 945px;
overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
list-style-type: none;
font: bold 28px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
ul a {
color: rgba(35,35,35,1.0);
position: relative;
display: block;
text-align: center;
}
nav {
text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
align-content: center;
}
nav ul li {
display: inline;
}
a:hover, a.hover {
color: rgba(109,109,109,1.0) !important;
}
a:visited, a.visited {
color: rgba(35,35,35,1.0);
}
a {
color: rgba(35,35,35,1.0);
}
#top-nav {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 933px;
height: 225px;
background: rgba(256,256,256,0.5);
border: 6px solid rgba(87,119,140,1);
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
}
#head-image {
position: relative;
top: 5px;
left: -280px;
z-index: 3;
}
#home-link {
top: 0px;
position: relative;
max-width: 100px;
width: 100px;
left: -10px;
display: block;
}
#about-link {
top: -32.5px;
position: relative;
width: 120px;
left: 150px;
display: block;
}
#contact-link {
top: -64px;
position: relative;
width: 100px;
left: 350px;
display: block;
}
#appointment-link {
position: relative;
top: -100px;
width: 350px;
top: 29px;
display: block;
left: 570px;
font: bold 28px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#contact-info {
position: relative;
text-align: right;
top: -170px;
left: 400px;
font-size: 28px;
font: bold 28px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: rgba(35,35,35,1.0);
text-decoration: none;
width: 520px;
}
#home-wrap {
height: 560px;
margin: 0 auto;
content-align: center;
}
#footer {
position: relative;
top: 20px;
background: rgba(256,256,256,0.5);
border: 6px solid rgba(87,119,140,1);
height: 70px;
}
#face-link {
font: 35px bold;
position: relative;
left: 15px;
top: -20px;
}
.group {
max-height: 100px;
}
#about-wrap {
position: relative;
top: 10px;
}
#about-us {
background: rgba(256,256,256,0.7);
border: 6px solid rgba(211,211,211,0.2);
font-size: 25px;
color: rgba(35,35,35,1);
font: bold;
top: 0px;
}
#about-info {
position: relative;
top: -25px;
padding-left: 5px;
height: 350px;
}
#hideme {
display: none;
position: relative;
top: 300px;
z-index: -5;
}
#unavailable-wrap {
position: relative;
top: 10px;
}
#coming-soon {
background: rgba(256,256,256,0.6);
color: rgba(35,35,35,1);
width: 933px;
height: 50px;
font: bold 28px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border: 6px solid rgba(211,211,211,0.2);
}
```

Here is a live version of the site to see:
http://www.757stylist.com/example/index.html

I would deeply appreciated the help if you can give me some.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do you want to set an fixed height? question is not clear bro.

Answer (score 0):

The code in `/js/dynamicpage.js` is setting the inline height rule to your pagewrap element:

```
$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
```

which doesn't make much sense because it calculates the current height of the element and adds it as inline style.

Since your question is not clear (in fact, there is no question), I can't help you more than that, but that's where the height is coming from. Other than that, your page wrapper element has no fixed height by any means - it will always extend as much as required by its children elements.

Comment: See I want to say that your right, but I have the same exact script on another webpage that I did and it did not cause a height issue there.  And one of the pages on it is even shorter than the homepage of this webpage.